# Silverlight5+WCF RIA and EF6 - is it possible?

Tags: entity-framework-6, wcf-ria-services

I’m trying to upgrade EntityFramework from v4 to v6 in our silverlight application. Since we user WCF RIA Services we have to upgrade that to OpenRia (since property WCF RIA only supports EF5).

However whenever I try to install “OpenRiaServices.EntityFramework” in our Silverlight app, I get:

Could not install package 'OpenRiaServices.EntityFramework 4.3.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Silverlight,Version=v5.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I think this is because the dll, targets “.NET Framework”, while Silverlight apps target "Silverlight" - question is: is there any way around it?

Second problem - that may, or may not be related to the first - is that even after I installed OpenRia I get following error during comppilation:

Error   206 The type 'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.EntityQuery`1' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

Of course the above DLL is part of the old RIA implementation, and cannot be referenced, any way around this?

Is it at all possible to use EF6 with silverlight applications that use RIA?

Answer (score 2):

We are using EF6 + OpenRia, but not through NuGet. All RIA dlls are stored in the "Lib" folder and referenced manually. Then I install "Open Ria Services Tooling and Templates", there is an VS extension, and not NuGet package.

.Ria (Silverlight 5) project has references:

```
OpenRiaServices.Data.DomainServices.dll (2.0.5.0)
OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.Client.dll (2.0.5.0) 
OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.Client.Web.dll (2.0.5.0)
```

.Ria.Web (.NET 4.5 Class library) project has references:

```
OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.EntityFramework.dll (4.0.0.0)
OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.Hosting.dll (4.0.0.0)
OpenRiaServices.DomainServices.Server.dll (4.0.0.0)
```

On the end of .Ria project file I add the next element:

```
<Import Project="..\..\..\Libs\Silverlight\OpenRia\CodeGen\OpenRiaServices.Silverlight.CodeGen.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\..\Libs\Silverlight\OpenRia\CodeGen\OpenRiaServices.Silverlight.CodeGen.targets')" />
```

(you must modify this string for your RIA .target reference)

EF 6.0.2 installed through NuGet.

Comment: Can you write step by step using Open Ria Services in Silverlight With Visual Studio 2013, plz?